# Artificial Neural Network Used to Compile Source Code

Tags: compiler-construction, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Would it be plausible to have an ANN that, when trained on millions of source code examples and the results from compiling them, that could compile source code into the correct output? For example, a ANN trained on Python source code and the resulting Python bytecode, that when given a Python program, could compile it to bytecode correctly.

Comment: Theoretically, sure. Is that your question?

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/No,_We_Need_a_Neural_Network.aspx

Comment: I know it is theoretically possible, but is it plausible? Is the number of samples it would need reasonable?

Comment: I'm not an expert on NN, but I don't think plausible by a wide margin given today's level of neural networks. You might be able to train it to detect syntactically valid python code, but even that's non trivial.

Comment: How about for a much simpler language or as a translator between languages, ie. BF and Ook.

Comment: hmm, I saw this in the morning, thought you might be interested https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3TP-AerYQU

Answer (score 4):

While this may be a very interesting epistemological question it is – in my opinion – not very interesting from a technical point of view: If you consider how AI programming developed you will find that the first approaches were oriented along processing the pure *logical* rules humans operate with while thinking. For instance the [General Problem Solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Problem_Solver) written by Simon, Shaw and Newell in 1957 (!) tried to operate on a very high abstract level following general *logical* principles.

The driving force was the belief that every problem could be formalized as a logical problem and solved by using knowledge bases with corresponding inference rules. Obviously this does not hold for something "trivial" as pattern recognition or (visual, auditive etc.) perception. Only *after* encountering such problems the idea of [Soft Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_computing) (including ANNs) gained publicity and it pointed out that for some problems formal approaches are not *appropriate*.

To cut a long story short: For the problem of compiling a formal (!) language into another one the formal (logical) approach is the *most appropriate*. In other words: while it *may* even be possible to open a can with a stone I would rather use a can opener ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not if you allow arbitrarily long programs.

If your NN is finite then it can only produce a finite number of compiled programs. But, if we allow arbitrarily long python programs then we have an infinite number of compiled programs. Thus, it is impossible for a finite NN to classify all of them.

Even with a bounded-length python programs I think it is highly unlikely this would work. NNs are good and classification tasks such as, 'Does this photo have a person in it?'. Compilation is a procedural problem. Two very similar python programs can have very different functionality (have you ever gotten your Python indentation wrong?).

Comment: Strictly speaking, no compiler allows arbitrarily long programs. This is not a meaningful limitation.

Comment: A finite compiler can compile an infinite number of different programs. A finite NN cannot. This is true regardless of what real-world compilers actually do.

Comment: A finite compiler can compile a very large number of different programs. I would hesitate to say there are an infinite number. All compilers have limits to recursive depth, number of functions or variables, source file size, etc. These limits are very large but not infinite.

Answer (score 0):

By Kolmogorov's superposition theorem, a neural network can reproduce any continuous function, and a compiler could be seen as a a very very complicated function. But it would not be at all practical.

Comment: What would be the dimensionality of this compiler-function? How would you map python source code to these `n` values? (Limiting the source code to n bytes? ) I don't see how compiling could be seen as a n-dimensional continuous function...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could compile arbitrarily long programs with a finite NN if you input a limited size code segment at a time. I think a way to prove that is that:

- compiling a program is a decidable problem (e.i. it can be solved by a Turing machine )
- you can build any logic gate from nand gate
- you can build a turing-complete machine using logic gate
- a neuron of a NN using as transfer function the function `f` 
  (where `f(x) = 1 if x <= 0, f(x) = 0 if x > 0`)
   and having only two input with equal weight is basicly a nand gate

so you can build a turing complete NN => there is a NN that can compile any program